# why does useEffect run once the window.innerWidth changes even though the second param in it is an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

`useEffect` in this code runs every time the window size changes, but the second parameter in `useEffect` is an empty array, I thought as long as the second parameter doesn't change compare to last time, the `useEffect` won't run

```js
import React from "react"

export default function WindowTracker() {
    
    const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth)
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth)
        })
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <h1>Window width: {windowWidth}</h1>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `useEffect` runs everytime, or could it rather be the event listener function added to window object in when the `udeEffect` hook? Also, you should add a `return` statement to your `useEffect` to remove the event listener when `WindowTracker` unmounts.

Comment: And where's removeEventListener? It should be returned from useEffect so that the handler is always removed when the component is unmounted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not that `useEffect` runs, rather the registered event listener callback. `useEffect` indeed runs once and registers the event listener once. But then afterwards, the listener callback is called.

You told the event listener to listen to `resize` right? So you should expect it to be called any time `resize` happens.

Also if you return function from your effect, it will run when component unmounts (because of empty dependencies); you can use that to remove listener:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  let cb = function () {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
  };
  window.addEventListener("resize", cb);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", cb);
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you console.log inside of useEffect, you will see it will actually gets run only once. Basically you have set once the event listener for the resize event. But you still have the registered event listener in place, which works as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

It is running once on the load because the dependencies array of `useEffect` is empty. If you want:

1. to run it every time a certain thing changes, pass that thing into the dependency array
2. to run it on every render then simply remove the square bracket.